# The file “MyApp.sqlite” couldn’t be opened Swift Core Data Error

Tags: swift, sqlite, core-data, crash

Core Data randomly crashes when `NSPersistentContainer.loadPersistentStores` is invoked.

This is how I'm loading the persistence store:

```swift
self.container.loadPersistentStores { storeDescription, error in
    if let error = error as NSError? {
         fatalError("Unresolved error  \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
            
    self.container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
    self.container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
}
```

After adding bugsnag I was able to know more about the error but still it's unclear why it's happening.

The actual error name is: `The file “MyApp.sqlite” couldn’t be opened.` with the following Mach error:

```json
{
  "code": "0x1",
  "exception_name": "EXC_BREAKPOINT",
  "subcode": "0x1914e93fc",
  "exception": 6,
  "code_name": "KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS"
}
```

This has happened quite a few times on different devices like iPhone XR, iPad Air 2, iPad7, iPhone14 and iPhone15, and different iOS version from 15.x to 17.x, but I cannot reproduce it on the simulator or my own device.

My guess is that for some reason, the `.sqlite` file gets corrupted, and I wonder if it's because of something the app is doing. Is there any way to investigate this further?

Has anyone seen this crash before? The only thread I found about this issue is this one: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/120158

Comment: "Core Data randomly crashes" At what line under what class or struct?